# Proof the next problem by using the pigeon hole principle

Tags: proof-writing, pigeonhole-principle

There are $2$ out of each $6$ points in a rectangle of $3\times 4$ with a distance $\le \sqrt 5$.

I know you need to divide the rectangle into $5$ equal parts so that in one part you'll get at least 2 points by the pigeon hole principle.

And I thought making rectangles of $2\times1$ in the entire rectangle but then you'd divide the rectangle in six parts.

Can somebody give me a hint on how to proceed?

Comment: try to add a triangle to each of the rectangles (it is possible if you add the triangle the right way).

Comment: I only get even number of triangles.

Comment: As I did it, you need two rectangles of 2*1 , two rectangles with a triangle and one pentagon looking like an house.

Comment: rectangles with a triangle= do you mean a triangle with an angle of 90°

Comment: added a picture.

Comment: how did you come up with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partition the rectangle $[0,4]\times[0,3]$ into $5$ regions by using the following 7 segments:
$$(0,1)(1,2),\;(1,2)(1,3),\;(1,2)(2,1),\;(2,1)(2,0),\;\;(2,1)(3,2),\;(3,2)(3,3),\;(3,2)(4,1).$$
The diameter of each region is $\sqrt{2^2+1^2}=\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: How can you come up with something like that? I've looked back into some books and found that picture too. There 3 pentagons and 2 half of those pentagons.

Comment: @AnonymousI I made several drawings keeping in mind that the diameter of the 5 regions should be at most the diagonal of a rectangle $2\times 1$.

Comment: Oh, yes that's something that's logical. I often lack of such insight.